# Why do I see [object Object] in my React input field instead of placeholder text?

Tags: html, reactjs, validation

I got the problem when implementing form input validation in React.
Once I open the form, there is always [object object] appear as the default input.
Here is the display:

[image]

Ideally, I want to have the below display:

[image]

And here is my code, any idea how shall I fix it?

```
const ErrorValidationLabel = ({ txtLbl }) => (
    <label htmlFor="" style={{ color: "red" }}>
        {txtLbl}
    </label>
);
const txtFieldState = {
    value: "",
    valid:true,
}
class Setting extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            name: {...txtFieldState, fileName:"name", required:true, requiredTxt:"Device ID is required"} ,
    }
    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handleNameSearch = this.handleNameSearch.bind(this);
    handleNameChange(event) {
        this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
    }
    handleNameSearch(event) {
        //http request call logic
    }
}
 render() {
        const renderNameError = this.state.name.valid? "" : <ErrorValidationLabel txtLbl={this.state.name.requiredTxt} />;
     return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleNameSearch}>
                                <label >
                                    Enter Your Device Id:
                            </label>
                                <Input  name="name" type="text" placeholder="ex:12345678910" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleNameChange} required/>
                                {renderNameError}
                                <Input type="submit"  value="Search Device" />
                            </form>
     );

}
```

Comment: Where is `thingName` in your state?

Comment: @T J sorry, it's the typo. has updated the code.

Comment: `this.state.name` is a big object. That is why it shows `[object Object]`.
Which property of it you want to assign to  textfield `value`? I think you want `this.state.name.value` according to your current code

Comment: the initial state is "", then the state will update based on the input. If I update value={this.state.name.value}, the [object object] will disappear, however whatever input I write, it will be always display "". No listen to my change for some reasons

Comment: Use `value={this.state.name.value} ` in the input

Comment: If I update value={this.state.name.value}, the [object object] will disappear,and I can't input any words, it will be always display "". No listen to my change for some reasons

Comment: You also need to update `this.handleNameChange` function to update the state with what you typed

Comment: OH, I found it.

Comment: "this.handleNameChange.bind(this)"... handleNameChange doesn't exist on "this". You wrote your code in the constructor. I'm not even sure the javascript is correct here. More handleNameChange out of the constructor and into the Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the value of your input to `this.state.name`, but `this.state.name` is an object.

```js
this.state = {
    name: {...txtFieldState, fileName:"name", required:true, requiredTxt:"Device ID is required"}
}
```

You should set it to `this.state.name.value`.

I should warn you, however, that the code `this.setState({ name: event.target.value })` will overwrite your entire `name` object, which likely isn't what you want.

You're using a spread operator already, so I would suggest

```js
this.setState(state => ({ name: { ...state.name, value: event.target.value } }))`.
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think the problem is I forget update name to name.value